# Difference between mysql.user table and mysql -u -h

Tags: mysql, database, hostname

Usually I run mysql using something like this:

```
mysql -h hostname -u user -p
(and then type password here)
```

but I wanted to know how is this related to the mysql.user table.
When I log in into mysql, and then I run:

```
select user,host from mysql.user
```

the db where I am logging in has a lot of different ips for host. Generally I see only '%' or 'localhost', but I am accessing a db that has many different ips (I changed the ips from the real ones for security reasons, but they look like this):

```
| user              | host          |
-------------------------------------
| user_1            | 54.211.18.65  |
| user_support      | 32.162.28.13  |
| user_admin        | 33.167.1.142  |
| user_super        | 35.161.72.123 |
```

Also, when I try to access user_1 using the mysql cli:

```
mysql -h mysql.example.com -u user_1 -p
```

it resolves mysql.example.com as my own ip, even when dig shows different ip, basically the [same as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925222/connecting-to-remote-mysql-host-resolves-to-my-ip-address) .
Please help understanding the difference between the -h host parameter, and the host in mysql.user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-h` in the `mysql` command line is the host you are connecting to. The `host` in the `mysql.user` table is the host the server will authenticate the user is coming from.

Its recommend that only IPs are used in `mysql.user` (aka `CREATE USER`) (and `skip-name-resolv` is enabled), as reverse DNS is a slow and unreliable authentication mechanism.